# Android Emulators can't access internet

Tags: android, emulation

I've been going through all the possible solutions found here, unfortunately, none of them worked for me. My manifest is setup properly; I have 3 differents AVD's and all of them show the 3G logo at the top right corner. I'm working on an App that requires an Internet connection; I tried simply going on the internet with the browser and it doesnt work. I don't have a proxy; I'm connected into a router; I'm on Windows Vista. I've tried adding the DNS of my PC in Run Configuration. The only issue I can see that could have screwed things up (although as far I can remember it didn't work before) I've had to update manually the Tools folder when Eclipse asked up to update to SDK 19. I kept getting an error that Eclipse couldn't overwrite the Tools folder. That's the solution I found on Google; of course, I kept a copy of my original tools folder for back up.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Firewall? Did you try to disable it for a moment? And check out the LogCat - maybe it says something about Internet connection on your emulator

Comment: Thanks for the help; the firewall didn't have anything to do with it, but I managed to find something else; I opened the prompt cmd; and entered this: emulator -avd(name of emulator) -dns-server 8.8.8.8 and it worked! Thanks again

Comment: I found your solution in many other threads, but I did it in eclipse's android -> launch, but it didn't help, but launching from command line really works.

Answer (score 0):

From [developer.android.com](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-networking.html):

> At startup, the emulator reads the list of DNS servers that your
>   system is currently using. It then stores the IP addresses of up to
>   four servers on this list and sets up aliases to them on the emulated
>   addresses 10.0.2.3, 10.0.2.4, 10.0.2.5 and 10.0.2.6 as needed.
>
> On Linux and OS X, the emulator obtains the DNS server addresses by
>   parsing the file /etc/resolv.conf. On Windows, the emulator obtains
>   the addresses by calling the GetNetworkParams() API. **Note that this
>   usually means that the emulator ignores the content of your "hosts"
>   file** (/etc/hosts on Linux/OS X, %WINDOWS%/system32/HOSTS on Windows).
>
> When starting the emulator at the command line, you can also use the
>   -dns-server  option to **manually specify the addresses of DNS servers to use**, where  is a comma-separated list of
>   server names or IP addresses. You might find this option useful if you
>   encounter DNS resolution problems in the emulated network (for
>   example, an "Unknown Host error" message that appears when using the
>   web browser).

So, I really tried to run the emulator from the commandline:

```
$ emulator @Name_of_my_avd -dns-server 192.168.0.1
```

where 192.168.0.1 - is my home router's ip. I found in system settings, that 192.168.0.1 is also my DNS server.

Everything works!

**UPD**: For MacOS: go to the System Preferences -> Network -> Advanced (in your active connection's tab) -> DNS. You will see the list of DNS servers your system using ([picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b5pPz.png)). When you edit this list and click Apply, your /etc/resolv.conf will update, so the emulator (**without option --dns-server**) will use it! **BUT**: in my case, emulator only use the first DNS server in the list! So if you want your emulator using some DNS server, simply **make it the first DNS in the list**.